# how do you output a string and change that string

Tags: java, class, while-loop, class-constructors

hello i am trying to create a specified amount of players in a game. I have looped the creation of players but everytime it loops it should go from making player1 to making player2 how do i construct a class which i defined in a separate file with that specific string ?

```
System.out.println("input starting monies in millions of dollaz");
double starterplayermoney = Double.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine());
System.out.println("input total players");
double doubletotalplayers = Double.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine()); 
int i = 1 ;
while(i<=doubletotalplayers){
    String playerstring = "player"+Integer.toString(i);
    player playerstring = new player();
    i++;    
}
```

Comment: `player p = new player(playerstring);` and fix your capitalization.

Comment: Learn about arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either an array or some collection of players. The thing is you are overwriting the reference to the player object in the next iteration here.

```
player playerString = new player();
```

Use an array like this:

```
Player [] playerString = new Player [2];
while( i <= doubletotalplayers){
playerString[i] = new Player();
```

}

Also, I am not sure why would you need a double value for number of players. Try using int.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question:

```
for (int i=1; i<=doubletotalplayers; i++) {
    String playerstring="Player "+i;
    player playerstring = new player();
}
```

Using a `for ()` loop saves lines, which is why i recommend using this, instead of the `while () {}` loop...

Now if you really want to keep the `while () {}` loop, than you need to do this...

```
int i = 1 ;
while(i<=doubletotalplayers){
    String playerstring = "player"+i;
    player playerstring = new player();
    i++;    
}
```